# Round Down Double in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have some cassandra data that is of the type double that I need to round down in spark to 1 decimal place.

The problem is how to extract it from cassandra, convert it to a decimal, round down to 1 decimal point and then write back to a table in cassandra.   My rounding code is as follows:

```
BigDecimal(number).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble
```

This works great if the number going in is a decimal but I dont know how to convert the double to a decimal before rouding.  My Double needs to be divided by 1000000 prior to rounding.

For example  510999000 would be 510.990  before being rounded down to 510.9

**EDIT:**  I was able to get it to do what I wanted with the following command.

```
BigDecimal(((number).toDouble) / 1000000).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble
```

Not sure how good this is but it works.

Comment: What type is ``number``?

Comment: Are you using DataFrames or is it an RDD of `number` values?

In the DataFrame case, I would define a UDF with your above function, you can the use `withColumn("number", myUDF(df("number")))` that will change your whole column to the desired format and you can then write back to Casandra.

In the RDD case, same idea except the function doesn't need to be a UDF and you can just use `map`

Comment: in this case `number` is 510999000

Comment: @FintanH could you provide an example of the RDD map scenario with `number` being 510999000 and being rouded down to 510.9

Comment: I believe it would look something like the following (excuse the editing/formatting):



`def f(number: Int):
    BigDecimal(number / 1000000).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble`

`val result = myRDD.map(f)`

Comment: That displays an error: `<console>:1: error: '=' expected but '(' found.
       def f(number: Int): BigDecimal(number / 1000000).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble`  pointing right between BigDecimal and (number / 10000000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer I was able to work with was:

```
 BigDecimal(((number).toDouble) / 1000000).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN).toDouble
```

Answer (score 15):

Great answer guys. Just chiming other ways to do the same

```
1. If using Spark DataFrame then ( x and y are DataFrames )
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.round 
   val y = x.withColumn("col1", round($"col1", 3))

2. val y = x.rdd.map( x => (x(0)*1000).round / 1000.toDouble )
```